# Azure mapping data flows - insert rows into two sink sequentially

Tags: azure-sql-database, etl, azure-data-factory, auto-increment, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am implementing a data flow in which I need to insert rows into two different sink and both of the sink are Azure SQL database tables.

The first sink i.e. the first Azure SQL database table has an auto generated ID column. After inserting values in the first table, we need to insert the values in the second sink which is an audit table.

Now the problem is that the identity column values generated in the first sink needs to be inserted in the second sink also. How can I get these auto incremented id column values to be inserted in the audit table.

Comment: You can set the ordering of sinks in the data flow settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, data is written to multiple sinks in a nondeterministic order. The execution engine writes data in parallel as the transformation logic is completed, and the sink ordering might vary each run. To specify an exact sink ordering, enable Custom sink ordering on the General tab of the data flow. When enabled, sinks are written sequentially in increasing order.

Refer below image for sink order.

[image]